# How to flash the "atmega328" with AVRDUDE?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, avrdude

I have an external device using an **ATmega328**, not a **ATmega328-P** as used by the Arduino Uno.

Now I want to use **AVRDUDE** and an Arduino Uno to flash a hex file on this chip. Therefore I removed the ATmega that came with the Arduino and popped in the one without the "-P".

With the Arduino IDE, it doesn't work, so I tried AVRDUDE:

```
avrdude -c arduino -P com3 -p ATMEGA328 -b 19200 -U flash:r:sdint.hex:r
```

However, I'm doing something wrong here, because it does not work:

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
>   ...

**What commandline should I use to flash an Arduino Uno with an ATmega328?**

Comment: Does it give any error messages?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide them. I would have to get my whole setup here and disassemble the other device again. But I get different error messages with different command lines I tried. And I tried a lot of them.

Comment: When posting an issue on SE, if there is an error message, include it in the post - the error message usually says exactly what's wrong, if you can decode it. I think you are unlikely to get an answer if you don't post the error message.

Comment: I will update it then. Give me just a few minutes.

Comment: I have updated it with the error message.

Comment: I always had troubles getting these to work :(

Comment: do you know if the atmega328 has the bootloader in it?

Comment: It's probably a blank atmega328, so without a bootloader, right? Try uploading the sketch using [Arduino as ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP)

Comment: I don't know if it has a bootloader. Could be that it doesn't. Uploading a sketch using the Arduino IDE doesn't work. So how do I burn a bootloader (without modifying its functionality)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be quite a common problem, and there are a number of problems, each with their own solution.

- Make sure you have selected the right chip
- Make sure you have selected the right serial port (when you unplug your board, it should disappear).
- Make sure you do not have anything plugged in to the tx & rx pins (usually 0 and 1).
- Make sure your Atmega chip has a bootloader on it
- Try another cable
- There may be a problem with your computer - try another computer
- If using another helps, try reinstalling the USB serial driver
- Try unplugging the Arduino board, holding down the reset switch, then plugging it in (still holding down reset); continue to hold down reset for about 5 seconds.
- make sure nothing else is trying to use your serial port
- Does your chip have a bootloader? Chips bought as part of an Arduino will, otherwise, it almost certainly doesn't, unless it specifically says (in the description of what you bought).

If it does not have a bootloader (or may not have a bootloader) you will need to set this up. You can either use the instructions here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard (which I never got working) or you can use an ICSP like the http://www.freetronics.com.au/products/usbasp-icsp-programmer-for-avr-arduino#.VlIY_2xifXs (which is what I use) - works great. They can be had for a few dollars from China.

Comment: I'm not even using the Arduino IDE, have you read my question? And... another cable........

Comment: I am sorry for offending you by mentioning the IDE, I have corrected it. As mentioned in my post, this error is a common error, and to save others from having to post another question, I have given as many possible answers as I could think of. Also note the answer at the bottom, which I have just added

Comment: Most likely I don't have a bootloader. The chip I'm using didn't come with an Arduino. It was part of a DIY circuit board. Can I burn a bootloader using an Arduino, without buying additional hardware?

Comment: Yes - using the first of the two links at the bottom - you'll need a working Arduino (with a bootlloader - you don't mention why you bought the new chip, so this may not be possible), and the separate chip (without the bootloader). Your mileage may vary, and if you have problems, I recommend getting the ICSP, which is cheap, and I've never had a problem with.